# equivilent of Excel HOUR() in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to take just the HOUR out of a date time column in PowerBI.
I tried

```
=HOUR([DateTime])
```

, which is converted into

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Custom", each HOUR([LocalTime]))
```

but I get

```
Expression error: The name 'HOUR' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.
```

I have scoured the internet, anyone have a place I can look for the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that within the query editor of power bi, the code is Power Query. That being said I went with this

```
=time.hour([LocalTime])
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There's a DAX function called HOUR, too.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634800%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396